# What does "favorable pharmacological profile" mean?

Tags: terminology

In the context of a new drug going through trials, what does "favorable pharmacological profile" mean?

e.g.

> YTX-7739, a potential disease-modifying therapy for Parkinson’s disease, was safe, well-tolerated, and found to have a **favorable pharmacological profile** when given to a group of healthy volunteers.

*ref:* https://parkinsonsnewstoday.com/2021/02/16/yumanity-therapeutics-potential-parkinsons-treatment-ytx-7739/

Answer (score 1):

The drug development process has several stages and before proceeding to human trials, parameters such as relative safety and probable therapeutic action are evaluated in order to assure safety and effectiveness on the treatment.

> Some information about the pharmacokinetics of a compound is also required before clinical evaluation is begun.  - Katzung and Trevor's Pharmacology

[image: image1]

In Katzung and Trevor's Pharmacology, pharmacological profile is defined as

[image: pharmacological profile]

Regarding your question, *favorable pharmacological profile* means that, in general, the pharmacological effect studied in the drug [YTX-7739] (cardiovascular, gastrointestinal, renal, CNS, etc.) had a beneficial behavior and ensured the therapeutic safety for the people being tested.